# convert a model.matrix in R to a group vector

Tags: r

In R, we can use `model.matrix()` to construct design matrices, for example,

```
grp.ids = as.factor(c(rep(1,8), rep(2,4), rep(3,2)))
x = model.matrix(~grp.ids)
```

gives the design matrix `x`:

```
   (Intercept) grp.ids2 grp.ids3
1            1        0        0
2            1        0        0
3            1        0        0
4            1        0        0
5            1        0        0
6            1        0        0
7            1        0        0
8            1        0        0
9            1        1        0
10           1        1        0
11           1        1        0
12           1        1        0
13           1        0        1
14           1        0        1
attr(,"assign")
[1] 0 1 1
attr(,"contrasts")
attr(,"contrasts")$grp.ids
[1] "contr.treatment"
```

However, if now I am given a design matrix `x` as above, and hope to get the "grouping vector" `grp.ids` by somehow manipulating on `x`. How can I do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe you could recover grp.id exactly as it was originally created because it's not possible to tell what the original values of the ids were.  You can create a vector that results in the same model.maxtrix though.

```
factor(apply(x, 1, paste, collapse = "."), labels = seq(ncol(x)))
```

However, this gets pretty close in this particular case.

---

The labels for the previous one give the order of 1, 3, 2 (instead of the desired 1, 2, 3) and that is because we get "1.0.0", "1.1.0", "1.0.1" as our actual output and sorted alphanumerically these give the order 1, 3, 2.  If we reversed the input string so we had "0.0.1", "0.1.1" and "1.0.1" then this would give the desired order so the following should work

```
factor(apply(x, 1, function(x){paste(rev(x), collapse = ".")}), labels = seq(ncol(x)))
```

Comment: thank you for the solution! I think it doesn't matter what number is used for each group since they're just levels of factors :)

Comment: BTW, is there any way to let the levels in increasing order? I currently have 1,3,2, but hope to get 1,2,3. In that way, when I reconstruct the model.matrix, I can get identical result. Thanks.